# Bug: Project based on self-made VS2012 Windows Store App template wont show up when using the charms or contracts?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

**Issue**

A project based on custom VS2012 Windows Store app template wont show up when using the charms or contracts.

**The steps I used:**

1. Created a new project, Blank one.
2. Export a Project Template based on that and let it automatically install
3. Restart VS just in case
4. Create new Project based on template
5. Set it as a share target
6. Run the Project

**Problem:**
App wont show up as Share target etc.

The problem is not with the implementation of the contract

Comment: I tried the exact steps and it just worked - also there is nothing I can think of that may cause the problem. I am running VS 2012 with the update 2 CTP installed. Here is my exported project template(http://sdrv.ms/XaFZ7X) so maybe you want to compare to what you exported & here is my app based on the template (http://sdrv.ms/XaG2Ao)

Comment: I traced the problem to be a package manifest issue. When you create a new app based on an automatically generated project template, the package name and package display name are not updated, which causes the confusion. In MVVM Light, I edited the project templates by hand to make sure that the GUID and display name are set correctly in new apps. I'll send that bug to MSFT.